# Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer SharedPreference

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

A very simple piece of code that returns me sometimes a ClassCastException.
There is nowhere in my code a place where I have saved Long into this property.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
   at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:307)
```

Maybe someone has an idea why does it happen?

```
var numberOfRepayment
    get() = sharedPrefs.getInt(UserSetting.NUMBER_OF_REPAYMENT.value, 0)
    set(value) {
        editor.run { putInt(UserSetting.NUMBER_OF_REPAYMENT.value, value).apply() }
    }
```

I have never personally met this issue but see it through Crashlytics

Comment: I think you are inputing Long value and retrieve Int value. so crashing

Comment: I mentioned above that I haven't put the long value into Int
It even doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: How many characters does your UserSetting.NUMBER_OF_REPAYMENT.value have?

Comment: Is it because you're passing the value of `UserSetting.NUMBER_OF_REPAYMENT.value` as the _key_? `SharedPreferences.Editor#putInt` requires 2 parameters to be passed in - the first being the _preference key to modify (of type `String`)_ and the 2nd is the new value for the preference (of type `int`). See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putInt(java.lang.String,%20int) for more info

Comment: @MateoHervas 17 char

Comment: @Edric UserSetting.NUMBER_OF_REPAYMENT.value has a String format = "numberOfRepayment"

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you haven't accidentally used a duplicate key name? That's the only possible cause I can think of.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yep
I checked it from the beginning. It affects only a small portion of users but for me, it's still interesting why it happens

Comment: I suppose in your next update you could catch the exception and then try to get the preference as a String and rethrow it so it shows up in the Play console for you to debug.

Comment: @Tenfour04
Thanks for the advice. I also thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

I just have experienced a similar problem. What I figured about it was a duplicate key as @Tenfour04 suggested in a comment.

In my case, *int cannot be cast to Long* error was occurring.

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException
    java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getLong (SharedPreferencesImpl.java:315)
```

At last, I found that my app used the same key as `int` once (and now I would use it as `Long`).

So, I solved my problem simply by changing the key name.